# Reflection get object property to sort a list

Tags: c#, sorting, reflection

I want to sort a list in c#, by a property of the objects stored in it. I have this:

```
if (sortColumn == "Login")
{
    if (sortDir == "ASC")
    {
        filteredList.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.Login, y.Login, true));
    }
    else
    {
        filteredList.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(y.Login, x.Login, true));
    }
 }
```

And it works fine, but I want to do it more generic, in order to not to have to know the field to sort. I have thinking in something like this:

```
//With sortColumn = "Login";
if (sortDir == "ASC")
{
    filteredList.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.GetType().GetProperty(sortColumn), y.GetType().GetProperty(sortColumn), true));
}
else
{
    filteredList.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(y.GetType().GetProperty(sortColumn), x.GetType().GetProperty(sortColumn), true));
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but this is what I want. Is it possible by any way?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `....GetProperty(sortColumn).GetValue(...)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the reflection code is not correct, look at this

```
PropertyInfo pi1 = typeof(x).GetProperty(sortColumn);
PropertyInfo pi2 = typeof(y).GetProperty(sortColumn);

//With sortColumn = "Login";
if (sortDir == "ASC")
{
    filteredList.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(pi1.GetValue(x, null), pi2.GetValue(y, null), true));
}
else
{
    filteredList.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(pi2.GetValue(y, null), pi1.GetValue(x, null), true));
}
```

i think this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks H-Bahrami!! This works to me, although with a little modification: I had to add a explicit cast to "pi1.GetValue(x, null)" and to "pi2.GetValue(y, null)" in order to make its return value to string: string.Compare((string)pi1.GetValue(x, null), (string)pi2.GetValue(y, null), true).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use for the same problem.

Usage looks like: `mySequence.OrderByPropertyName("Login", SortDirection.Descending)`.

```
public enum SortDirection
{
    Ascending,
    Descending
}

public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderByPropertyName<T>
(
    this IEnumerable<T> items,
    string propertyName,
    SortDirection sortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending
)
{
    var propInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
    return items.OrderByDirection(x => propInfo.GetValue(x, null), sortDirection);
}

public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderByDirection<T, TKey>
(
    this IEnumerable<T> items,
    Func<T, TKey> keyExpression,
    SortDirection sortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending
)
{
    switch (sortDirection)
    {
        case SortDirection.Ascending:
            return items.OrderBy(keyExpression);
        case SortDirection.Descending:
            return items.OrderByDescending(keyExpression);
    }
    throw new ArgumentException("Unknown SortDirection: " + sortDirection);
}
```

Comment: @L.B Hah, I forgot that was an extension, sorry. Updated! Also the direction argument should probably be an `enum`.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked against dateTime and working correctly.

```
    List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();
    list.Add(DateTime.Now);
    list.Add(DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(2));

    list.Sort((x, y) => (Convert.ToString(x.GetType().GetProperty("DayOfYear").GetValue(x)).CompareTo(Convert.ToString(y.GetType().GetProperty("DayOfYear").GetValue(y)))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding off of verdesmarald post I separated Ascending and Descending into separate methods and added ThenBy methods:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace System.Linq
{
    public static class IEnumerableExtensions
    {
        enum SortDirection
        {
            Ascending,
            Descending
        }

        public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T>
            (this IEnumerable<T> items,
            string propertyName)
        {
            var propInfo = typeof (T).GetProperty(propertyName);
            return items.OrderByDirection(x => propInfo.GetValue(x, null), SortDirection.Ascending);
        }

        public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> ThenBy<T>
            (this IOrderedEnumerable<T> items,
            string propertyName)
        {
            var propInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
            return items.ThenByDirection(x => propInfo.GetValue(x, null), SortDirection.Ascending);
        }

        public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderByDescending<T>
            (this IEnumerable<T> items,
            string propertyName)
        {
            var propInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
            return items.OrderByDirection(x => propInfo.GetValue(x, null), SortDirection.Descending);
        }

        public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> ThenByDescending<T>
            (this IOrderedEnumerable<T> items,
            string propertyName)
        {
            var propInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
            return items.ThenByDirection(x => propInfo.GetValue(x, null), SortDirection.Descending);
        }

        private static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderByDirection<T, TKey>
            (this IEnumerable<T> items,
            Func<T, TKey> keyExpression,
            SortDirection sortDirection)
        {
            switch (sortDirection)
            {
                case SortDirection.Ascending:
                    return items.OrderBy(keyExpression);
                case SortDirection.Descending:
                    return items.OrderByDescending(keyExpression);
            }
            throw new ArgumentException("Unknown SortDirection: " + sortDirection);
        }

        private static IOrderedEnumerable<T> ThenByDirection<T, TKey>
            (this IOrderedEnumerable<T> items,
                Func<T, TKey> keyExpression,
                SortDirection sortDirection)
        {
            switch (sortDirection)
            {
                case SortDirection.Ascending:
                    return items.ThenBy(keyExpression);
                case SortDirection.Descending:
                    return items.ThenByDescending(keyExpression);
            }
            throw new ArgumentException("Unknown SortDirection: " + sortDirection);
        }
    }
}
```